# Request showing Response data "Object moved to here" in Jmeter Testing asp dot net

Tags: asp.net, testing, automation, jmeter, performance-testing

While executing jmeter script recording in asp dot net webpage, the request is given as POST request in script but in results it shown as a node having 2 request, the first one is having "POST" request but the response data for that request appears as "Object moved to here". The follow redirected option is enabled. The second request is going to the correct page and posting the data but the request is given as GET. Is there any other methods by which the Object moved to here/Response code 302 can be avoided?

Added the screenshots for View state and Event validation post processors and the request in which the post processors are used.

Attached screenshots.

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image: POST processor for View State]
[image: Post processor for event validation]
[image: Request details]
[image: Response details- Login Get]
[image: Response details login Post]
[image: Request]
[image: response1][image: response2]

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing the extraction of either a header or hidden form .

Usually for Asp it's viewstate , check this blog :

- http://www.markschabacker.com/blog/2013/05/10/jmeter_with_webforms_authentication/

I see in your login request a __ViewStateEncrypted, did you also variabilize it ?

Compare a login recorded with login by jmeter to see the differences.

One other possibility, try for login switching from Httpclient4 to Java implementation.

Comment: I have followed the same and added the view state and event validation in the script initially itself but it is showing the error.

Comment: show your test plan updated and zoom on post processor and element that uses the extracted value

Comment: I have added the screenshots for post processors and the element which uses the extracted value.

Comment: ok now run it and show view results tree zooming on replaced values for eventValidation and viewState

Comment: Added screenshots.. Please check

Comment: I want screenshot showing the first post request that uses the eventValidation, don't use the regexp tester, just text and select request tabl , thx

Comment: I have added screenshot of the first post request.

Comment: I updated my answer, sorry with current informations no more ideas